# Flutter Pass Function With Generic Parameter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to write a Typehead package. In case of that, I need to pass functions with generic parameters but I am getting a type error.

Here is my simplified code:

**Models:**

```
class BaseModel {
  BaseModel({required this.title});
  String title;
}

class SearchModel extends BaseModel {
  SearchModel({required super.title, required this.myText});
  String myText;
}
```

**TypeHead Class:**

```
class HorizontalTypeHead<T extends BaseModel> extends StatefulWidget {
  const HorizontalTypeHead({
    Key? key,
    required this.onLookup,
    required this.onSelected,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Future<Iterable<T>> Function(String value) onLookup;
  final Function(T model) onSelected;

  @override
  State<HorizontalTypeHead> createState() => _HorizontalTypeHeadState<T>();
}

class _HorizontalTypeHeadState<T extends BaseModel> extends State<HorizontalTypeHead> {
  Iterable<T> _data = [];
  List<Widget> renderColumn(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> list = [
      TextField(
        onChanged: (String? val) async {
          if (val != null) {
            _data = await widget.onLookup(val) as Iterable<T>;
            setState(() {});
          }
        },
      ),
    ];
    if (_data.isNotEmpty) {
      list.add(
        SizedBox(
          height: 100,
          child: ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: _data
                .map((e) => ResultWidget<T>(
                    model: e, onSelected: widget.onSelected))
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return list;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: renderColumn(context));
  }
}
```

**Result Widget:**

```
class ResultWidget<T extends BaseModel> extends StatelessWidget {
  const ResultWidget({required this.model, required this.onSelected, Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  final T model;
  final Function(T selected) onSelected;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
        onTap: () => onSelected(model),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          child: Text(model.title),
        ));
  }
}
```

My main goal is to access data in SearchModel (myText field). But when I am assigning SearchModel as type, I get a type error.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Future<Iterable<SearchModel>> onLookup(String pattern) async {
    return [SearchModel(title: "title", myText: "myText")];
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: HorizontalTypeHead<SearchModel>(
        onSelected: ((model) => print(model.myText)), //I need to get myText
        onLookup: onLookup,
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

> _TypeError (type '(SearchModel) => void' is not a subtype of type '(BaseModel) => dynamic')

I would like to ask what I need to do for accessing SearchModel without any error from main class. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made generic my state class and solved it :)

```
    class _HorizontalTypeHeadState<T extends BaseModel> 
extends State<HorizontalTypeHead<T>>
```

instead of

```
    class _HorizontalTypeHeadState<T extends BaseModel> 
extends State<HorizontalTypeHead>
```